# jQuery not selecting RadioButton by CSS class?

Tags: jquery

I have a table of records with an Approve and Deny radio button. I've created a Reset button to clear all buttons that works but I'm trying to get the "Approve All" and "Deny All" button to clear all radiobuttons and then select all of the buttons in either of the respective CSS class.

With the following code I am able to see the Alert message as well as it will uncheck all of the radiobuttons but it will not check the ones with the CSS class. From my research this looks as though it should work and I don't see any errors in the Dev Tools.

Here is the jQuery. The alert works and the next line that unchecks all buttons works but the third line where it tries to find all buttons with a class of .rdoApprove doesn't seem to work.

```
$("#approveAll").click(function () {
    alert("approve clicked");

    $('input:radio').attr('checked', false);

    $('input:radio.rdoApprove').attr('checked', true);
});
```

This is from the code in the browser when I inspect the element. I can see the CSS class and I copied and pasted the name to make sure I didn't misspell something.

[image]

Comment: Please convert to a [mcve] snippet (`<>` toolbar button in the editor).

Comment: Everyone is getting so DownVote happy lately. @AlanLarimer...I don't understand what you are wanting here. You want me post all of my code from the page?

Comment: You have used an image of code in your question.  Is the [mcve] article unclear?  It helps all to understand the actual issue and often reveals the solution to the OP.

Comment: use .prop() rather than .attr()

Comment: View Source won't let me copy and paste the code. I didn't want to type that line of code so I did a quick image to show how the code rendered out in browser. It's not part of the code, it just shows what was rendered.

Comment: @Snowmonkey...that worked! I don't understand why using .attr() to remove all the checked worked but I have use .prop() to select it? Is that because of the reference for the CSS class? BTW: post as an answer so I can give you credit.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going on, it doesn't seem to matter what order you use the selectors. The only issue I noted was that of prop() vs. attr()

```js
$("input:radio").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).prop("class") );
});

$(".choose-male").on("click", function(){
  $("input:radio.genderBtn-male").prop("checked", true)
})

$(".choose-female").on("click", function(){
  $("input.genderBtn-female:radio").prop("checked", true)
})

$(".choose-other").on("click", function(){
  $("input.genderBtn-other[type='radio']").prop("checked", true)
})
```

```css
span {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="genderBtn-male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input class="genderBtn-female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input class="genderBtn-other"type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form> 
<hr />

<span class="choose-male">Male?</span>
<span class="choose-female">Female?</span>
<span class="choose-other">not quite sure?</span>
```

Comment: The use of .prop() instead of .attr() fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

See if selecting only on Class will make a difference (i.e. `$('.rdoApprove').attr('checked',true)`)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before posting thinking that could have been an issue but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

I don't really understand where is the problerm, maybe because my english not really good. So can you provide anything that's an explain it more clear by code (we try it) in jsfiddle?

But maybe you can try this:

```
$("#approveAll").click(function () {
    alert("approve clicked");

   $('input:radio').each(function(i){
      if( $(this).hasClass('rdoApprove') ){
        $(this).attr('checked','checked');
      } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      }
   });

});
```

LIVE:

```js
$("#approveAll").click(function () {
    alert("approve clicked");

   $('input:radio').each(function(i){
      if( $(this).hasClass('rdoApprove') ){
        $(this).attr('checked','checked');
      } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      }
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="genderBtn-male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/> Male<br/>
  <input class="genderBtn-female rdoApprove" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> Female<br/>
  <input class="genderBtn-other" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"/> Other 
<br/><br/>
<button id="approveAll">CLICK this approveAll button</button>
```